# How to clear Texboxes attached with message boxes in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

For Learning the coding I built this application. It has Three text boxes.1 and 2 to enter numbers and 3 is to sum of 1 and 2. Button 2 is to get sum and 1 to clear textboxes.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        If TextBox1.Text >= 101 Then
         MsgBox("Enter numbers between 0 and 100")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        TextBox3.Text = Int(TextBox1.Text) + Int(TextBox2.Text)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        TextBox1.Clear()
        TextBox2.Clear()
        TextBox3.Clear()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here I have limited the `TextBox1` to get numbers between 0 and 100. if it is over 100, displays a warning massage box.

When  I click the clear button it gives an error. It doesn't clear. after deleting textbox 1 clearing code it works fine. I mean textbox 2 & 3 clear fine. There is a problem with Textbox 1. The reason i believe is the msgbox attached it. I need to keep Msgbox. 
How do I clear them?

Comment: Try `TextBox1.Text = ''` instead of clear and see if it works.

Comment: What error do you get? Consider moving this 'TextBox1.Text >= 101' to the Validate method.

Comment: Thanks  Scath.Unfortunately it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Dear Andrew Mortimer, please tell me how to move this 'TextBox1.Text >= 101' to the Validate method

Comment: Any help please !

Comment: Problem is not with the clear, its the value changed that checks the text of the control and compares it to 1 and 100.  Since its null.. it throws and error.  You can just check first if the text property of your textbox is null, and if it is, you dont need to test for 1 and 100, just display message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to suppress text changed event. See [TextBoxBase.Clear Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.clear(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

```
Public Class Form1

   Private flag As Boolean  

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
      ' Check the flag to prevent code re-entry. 
      If flag = False Then
        ' Set the flag to True to prevent re-entry of the code below.
        If TextBox1.Text >= 101 Then
         MsgBox("Enter numbers between 0 and 100")
        End If
      End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        TextBox3.Text = Int(TextBox1.Text) + Int(TextBox2.Text)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        flag = True
        TextBox1.Clear()
        TextBox2.Clear()
        TextBox3.Clear()
        flag = False
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: wonderful coding dear IvanH. Thanks a million brother....works like a charm. And thanks all....

Answer (score 0):

`TextBox1.Clear()` will fire `TextBox1_TextChanged()`.

This line will do an implicit conversion from text to integer - it will fail with an error on blank or text entries:

```
If TextBox1.Text >= 101 Then
```

Instead, try this:

```
Dim number As Integer
If Int32.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, number) Then
   If number >= 101 Then
      MsgBox("Enter numbers between 0 and 100")
   End If
End If
```

Comment: Dear Stephen Kennedy, i learnt that the "TryParse worth million" from you. Thanks........